# Default template for ckeditor in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, symfony4, symfony-forms

My form builder looks like this:

```php
...
        $builder->add('answer', CKEditorType::class, [
            'config' => [
                'required' => true,
                'extraPlugins' => 'templates',
                'templates'    => 'my_template',
            ],
            'templates' => array(
                'my_template' => array(
                    'templates'  => array(
                        array(
                            'title'       => 'My Template',
                            'description' => 'My awesome template',
                            'html'        => '<p>Crazy template :)</p>',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
            //'defaultTemplate' => 'my_template' ???
        ]);
...
```

I am using symfony 4.4 and ckeditor.
How can I set up the default template for CKEditor in `php` file?
There is nothing about this in the documentation.